# Logic operators in if statments

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, logic

So i am writing a calculator as an exercise in c++, were you first select operators `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` by inputting a, s, m or d. The calculator works fine, except for a filter i set up to respond with an error if the user inputs something other than a, s, m or d. The filter is an if statement:

```
if(Opperator=='a'||'s'||'m'||'d')
    {
        //some code
    }

    else
    {
        //"Operatorfault"
        cout <<"opperatorfeil";
    }
```

Even though the "operator" has other `char` values than those the if statement is suppose to execute, the code within the if statement is still executed. The whole code is below. The outputs and variables are in Norwegian, but i have tried to translate in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//The calculator function
int Kalkulator(int IN1, int IN2, char Opperator)
{
    int Svar;

    //Detects witch operator the user choose, and preforms the assigned operation
    if(Opperator=='a')
    {
        Svar=IN1+IN2;
    }

    if(Opperator=='s')
    {
        Svar=IN1-IN2;
    }

    if(Opperator=='m')
    {
        Svar=IN1*IN2;
    }

    if(Opperator=='d')
    {
        Svar=IN1/IN2;
    }

    //Returns the answer
    return Svar;
}

int main()
{
    //Input a, s, m or d for addition, subtraction, multiplication or division, respectively
    cout <<"Skriv \"a\" for addisjon, \"s\" for subtraksjon, \"m\" for multipliksjon, og \"d\" for  divisjon";

    cout <<endl;
    cout <<endl;

    char Opperator;

    cin >>Opperator;
    cout <<endl;

    //Checks if the input is valid
    if(Opperator=='a'||'s'||'m'||'d')
    {
        cout <<"Skriv inn det første tallet du vil gjøre opperasjonen på, trykk derreter enter, og skriv inn det andre";
        cout <<endl;
        cout <<endl;

        int IN1;
        int IN2;

        cin >>IN1;
        cin >>IN2;
        cout <<endl;

        //"The answer is"
        cout << "Svaret er: ";
        //Calls the calculator function, and inputs the values it has gathered, then prints the answer
        cout <<Kalkulator(IN1, IN2, Opperator);
    }

    else
    {
        //"Operatorfault"
        cout <<"opperatorfeil";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `if (Opperator=='a'||'s'||'m'||'d')` work? Shouldn't it be `if ((Opperator == 'a') || (Opperator == 's') || ...)`, should it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That makes the it work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if(Opperator=='a'||'s'||'m'||'d')
```

you can NOT test for equality (or inequality) like this. The code executes as the equivalent of

```
if (Operator == (result of boolean ORs))
```

You have to test for equality individually:

```
if ((op == 'a') || (op == 's') || etc...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your if statement.  In C++, when you are comparing the same variable to multiple values, for example if opperator is a, m, s, d, you need to restate the variable for each comparison.

```
if( Opperator=='a' || Opperator=='s' || Opperator=='m' || Opperator=='d' )
```

Instead of your current if statement.

Also, as a tip, a switch statement is much better in these cases, you can simply state

```
int ans;
switch (customerPackage) {
  case 'a':
    ans = int1 + int2;
  case 's':
    ans = int1 - int2;
  case 'd':
    ans = int1 * int2;
  case 'm':
    ans = int1 / int2;
  default:
    string ans;
    ans = "invalid input";
}
cout <<ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just break it out like so,

```
if (Opperator == 'a' || 
    Opperator == 's' ||
    Opperator == 'm' ||
    Opperator == 'd')
{
    // Good values
}
else
{
    // Bad values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Opperator=='a'||'s'||'m'||'d')
```

It checks whether Opperator is equal to 'a', if not then 's' always returns true and so all logic becomes true.

You can use `if` statement:

```
if (Opperator == 'a' || Opperator == 's' || Opperator == 'm' ||  Opperator == 'd') {
    // my calc works well
} else {
    // again my calc works well
}
```

OR you can use `switch`:

```
switch(Opperator) {
    case 'a':
    case 's':
    case 'm':
    case 'd': // do normal operation here
              break;
    default:  // error handle
              break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must test each char for equality:

```
if(Opperator=='a'||Opperator=='s'||Opperator=='m'||Opperator=='d') {
    ...execute
} else {
    ...execute something else
}
```

If you want to be fancy you can use `algorithm::anyOf()`.

```
#include <algorithm>

const std::vector<char> validValues{'a','s','m','d'};

if(any_of(validValues.begin(),
          validValues.end(),
          [&](const char &x) { return x == Opperator; }) {
    // good values
} else {
    // bad values
}
```